When I register blueprints within init then they fail to register, why is that?
There are dozens of questions about disappearing blueprints on StackExchange, but this may be the tersest example yet. Assume app.py is in upper folder and __init__.py, etc are in a subfolder "test". The following fails:
app.py
from test_bad import create_app

# Start the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        print(rule)
        
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)

__init__.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from . routes import dash 

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__) 
    app.register_blueprint(dash)
    return app

routes.py
from flask import Blueprint

# Define the blueprint
dash = Blueprint('dash', __name__)

views.py
from . routes import dash 

@dash.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return '<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>'

@dash.route('/verify', methods=['GET','POST'])
def check_verification():
    return '<html><body><h1>And Farewell!</h1></body></html>'


whereas the following works just fine:
app.py
from test_good.views import create_app

# Start the app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        print(rule)
        
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)

__init__.py

routes.py
from flask import Blueprint

# Define the blueprint
dash = Blueprint('dash', __name__)

views.py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from . routes import dash 

@dash.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return '<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>'

@dash.route('/verify', methods=['GET','POST'])
def check_verification():
    return '<html><body><h1>And Farewell!</h1></body></html>'

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__) 
    app.register_blueprint(dash)
    return app

Looking at the printed endpoint rules, you can see that in the "bad" case those endpoints did not get added to app (or app got "refreshed" somehow). Whereas in the good case the endpoints are just fine.
From a code structure perspective, I would have thought that __init__ was the correct place, but apparently not.
What is a yet better way to write this? [Or am I missing something]. Thanks,

It's weird how similar this is to the text book examples :-(

Found my bug.
routes.py doesn't know that views.py has a whole bunch of subroutines.
So when __init__.py evaluates from . routes import dash then it defines dash.deferred_functions with precisely zero entries. That value of dash attribute is then passed to app.register which activates all the deferred functions (i.e. none) and notifies app about zero endpoints.
However, when I call from test_good.views import create_app then I have loaded up all the deferred functions before the call to app.register. In the debugger, you can see that dash.deferred_functions evaluates to
[
<function Blueprint.add_url_rule.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002178B842840>,
<function Blueprint.add_url_rule.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002178B842980>
]

even before the call to app = Flask(__name__). I guess what @dash.route does is simply append this list. Anyway, so this time around, when I call app.register_blueprints(dash) then the two deferred functions are ready to be added to the add_url_rule and everything is fine.
A quick fix is to put the line from . import views  at the bottom of routes.py, and then the create_app can happily reside within __init__.py

OMG. And then the existence of a Blueprint means you have to move templates folder from the top folder down into the same folder as  __init__.py. That was a nasty little trick too.
